# Запись в файл c++-cli

Tags: файлы, c++-cli

Мой код просто дописывает в файл строку из textBox3, но надо что бы записывал, то есть что бы не было предыдущих записей.

```
using namespace System::IO;

private: System::Void button4_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

    StreamWriter^ f = gcnew StreamWriter("Result.txt", true);
    f->Write(textBox3->Text);
    f->Write("\n");
    f->Close();
    MessageBox::Show(this, "Запись в файл выполнена", "Сообщение", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
}
```

Comment: Если используется не си++ то не ставьте метку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StreamWriter^ f = gcnew StreamWriter("Result.txt", false);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin куда ответ разворачивать? В одной строке ошибка.

Comment: @Blackmeser, премного вам благодарен